# How to save login user to redux state

Tags: reactjs, axios, mern

Hello guys i have a login function in my mern project in this project i'm trying redux-toolkit to save the current info of user, but i encounter error while doing this. The problem is everytime user make a api request that user need a `TOKEN`, to get the token im using redux-persist to save the token in session storage everytime i open/launch my application its says `error user is not existed` because the session is not loaded and the `user` is not yet existed. How to handle this problem, any other solutions ? thanks.

useFetch :

```
import axios from 'axios';


const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5000";

const TOKEN = (JSON.parse(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("persist:root")).user).currentUser?.accessToken);


export const publicRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL
})

 
export const userMethod = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    headers: {token: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`}
})
```

apiCall :

```
import { loginFailure, loginStart, loginSuccess } from "./userRedux"
import { publicRequest, userMethod } from '../useFetch';
import { addProduct, removeItem } from "./cartRedux";
import { createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";


export const login = async (dispatch, user) => {
    dispatch(loginStart());
    try {
        const res = await publicRequest.post("/login", user);
        dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data));
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch(loginFailure());
    }
}
```

userRedux :

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'


const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: "user",
    initialState: {
       currentUser: null,
       isFetching: false,
       error: false
    },
    reducers: {
        loginStart: (state) => {
            state.isFetching = true;
        },
        loginSuccess: (state, action) => {
            state.isFetching = false;
            state.currentUser = action.payload;
        },
        loginFailure: (state) => {
            state.isFetching = false;
            state.error = true;
        },
        logout: (state) => {
            state.currentUser = null
        }
    }
})

export const { loginStart, loginSuccess, loginFailure, logout } = userSlice.actions
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 1):

You typically don't save the entire user object into storage because doing so can easily create scenarios where the user info is desynced if updated on another device.

What you are doing now, by persisting only the *token*, is correct. But what you are missing is that on every hard page reload, there needs to be some action which is fired which results in a call to the API to get the user details from the server side for the given token. This is different to the logon endpoint, which issues the token itself. This endpoint would take a token you already have and just sends back the user details for that token.

Then you can put that user info in redux state (but not persisted).

Typically you make this API endpoint available on something like `/users/me`.

Comment: Ok i get what you mean so in order to get the data from the server side, i need to create function getToken in folder apiCall and call that function in every page with useEffect ?

Comment: You probably would call it at some place high up in your application like `App.js` or your equivalent. That way, it will run that effect when the user first hits the application or on hard refresh.

Comment: can you give rough example please, i already tried bur i have a problem with how to send jwt token from server to client. In the login function i can send the token because i already created the token. If i have another get endpoint to send only the token, that means i have to sign new jwtToken ?